# Aparecendo símbolos ao importar banco de dados sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Havia um banco de dados em um servidor A. Apaguei esse servidor e estou criando um novo servidor B.

Ao importar o arquivo.sql, para o servidor B, os nomes estão todos com errados.

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para que no banco de dados o que tiver acento apareça seu devido acento?

No inicio do SQL tem isso:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```

Nas criação das tabelas esta assim:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Obrigado.

Comment: É problema de codificação, veja as respostas nesta outra pergunta para entender o que você precisa configurar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é possível corrigir isso na importação do banco de dados? No meu arquivo SQL tem esse comentário ````/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;````

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Nas criação das tabelas esta assim: ````ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;````